# Why is helium considered as a non-metal?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, noble-gases

How can helium be considered as a non-metal based on its chemical properties? Helium is a noble gas; it does not take part in chemical reactions under ordinary conditions. But non-metals tend to gain electrons to form negative ions. Also, there are many chemical properties that helium does not show as a non-metal. Then how can be helium considered as a non-metal by looking at is chemical properties?

Comment: On chemical properties helium is like a noble gas not a metal. It is chemically unreactive like noble gases but unlike metals; it is not electrically conductive even as a solid, unlike metals. Exactly which properties are metal like and not noble gas like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal

Answer (score 0):

- Metal atoms share electrons.
- Non-metals don't.
- Helium atoms do not share electrons. QED (this ain't quantum electrodynamics).

Of course, there are semimetals, but again, He doesn't qualify, so it's not germane to the answer.